# How can I upload a file from my laptop to sharepoint?

Tags: sharepoint-server

I really need help in this subject because I have a VBA script running and I want powershell to run my VBA script and then upload the data to SharePoint. Can someone please help me?. I also use SharePoint online management PowerShell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pnp powershell library has a cmdlet for this: add-pnpfile. See example #3 in the docs [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnpfile?view=sharepoint-ps):

```
Add-PnPFile -Path .\sample.doc -Folder "Shared Documents" -Values @{Modified="1/1/2016"}
```